# ASP.net MVC HTML Table insert data to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post

I am using ASP.net MVC to get data from a database and output this into a html table. This datatable contains several products and I want to add a button to the end of each row. When the user presses this button it should add all the details to a table "SelectedProducts".

However I am unsure how to proceed, having looked at using CRUD, I dont think its possible as I just want to get this data and save it into a new database.